# How to use Facebook jsdk?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to know what is the best way to save some informations about the user in my database.

With this code I get that informations:

```
 FB.api({
     method: 'fql.query',
     query: 'select first_name, last_name, sex, pic from user where uid=me()'
 }, function (response) {
    // save informations
 });
```

But now, how can I put these informations in my database ?

Is ajax the best way to do that ?

Or I have to use PHP sdk in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But now, how can I put these informations in my database ?

In the lines commented "save informations", simply AJAX the data to your webserver.

> Is ajax the best way to do that ?

Yes, AJAX is the best way to get data instantly back to your server once the FB.api call has completed.

> Or I have to use PHP sdk in this case ?

No, in this case your code is running client-side.  Why duplicate it server-side too?  No need.  Just remember, the less things your server has to do (because you off-load much of it to the client) the better for your server's performance and lower cost to maintain the server.

Comment: maybe you are right but ı think if you want to chose ajax or php sdk its depend on your application. maybe i am wrong, ı always use php sdk on my apps.

Comment: yeah, if you've got spare server power and all of your authentication is happening server side (or you AJAX up the accessToken from the client) then that's a pretty good solution.  But if you're already using clientside JS SDK, then you might as well continue to run any API interaction via the JS SDK as it already has the accessToken and is ready to go.